# Action not found when a page is not in a root

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, jquery-jtable

I use jtable in ASP.NET WebForms and I have all pages in a ~/Pages/ folder. When loading a webpage with jtable, the network profiler in Google Chrome tells me that StudentList in ~/Pages/Default.aspx could not be found (error 404) along with popup window with this message

> An error occured while communicating to the server.

the action part of jtable looks like follows

```
actions: {
   listAction: '/Default.aspx/OfficerList',
```

But when I move this file to root directory, everything is all right.

**Why is that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `/` from listAction

```
listAction: 'Default.aspx/OfficerList',
```

Because if you have `/Default.aspx/OfficerList'` this then it will look for `Default.aspx` on root.